# click to start new activity in grid view

Tags: java, android

I have grid view in my application. on click of each image in gridview  new activity should start.
now when I click on them, a toast appears.

how I manage setOnClicklistener in my adaptor I can't have startactivity.

```
enter code here:
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MyActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
    holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

and here is myactivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
GridView gv;
Context context;
ArrayList prgmName;
public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onItemClickListener` on `GridView`

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

        if(position==0){
            Intent iinent= new Intent(MyActivity.this,secondactivity.class);
            startActivity(iinent);
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: But my main problem was that my adapter wasn't in my activity , I couldn't access my position in if .

Comment: you need to override the onItemClickListener in your activity